# Не работает управление слайдером GSAP

Tags: javascript, gsap

Приветствую и с праздниками!!!!

В общем получилось сделать корректно работающий слайдер, который меняет сюжеты как надо и не тормозит при выходе в другую вкладку. Встала задача управлять перелистыванием слайдов. Сейчас - функция работает в промежуточном варианте, это - тестовый ивент листенер, остальные - допишу по аналогии, когда разберусь. Логи стоят для проверки состояния и на листенере по логам видно, что функция gsaping работает корректно, но её результат не отображается. При этом, если просто в потоке при загрузке запустить эту функцию и в неё передать индекс существующего изображения - она сработает корректно, в листенере я делаю ресет и фактически на код при загрузке пускаю эту функцию с индексом существующего изображения, но....

Буду рад любой помощи

````
```
https://codepen.io/Guss_H/pen/vYezjZJ
```
````

Comment: И вот ради этой анимации уровня CSS вы использовали gsap? Куда мир катится?!

Comment: @DiD Эммм... Я не зря это делаю и вопрос не подразумевает конкурс на самый длинный программистский))))
Если интересны причины:
1. Контролируемый слайдер в разы быстрее писать именно с GSAP - меньше кода, у меня есть версия подобной задачи на CSS+JS -  кода там вагон
2. Есть некоторая особенность стабильности работы слайдера в условиях оптимизации браузерами таймаутов, на пример: при переводе вкладки в неактивную и последующем возврате, там надо колупнуть ещё ряд моментов = дописать код. GSAP - решает этот и ещё ряд моментов, для этого и выбран. С багом разобрался - сегодня сам закрою топик.

Comment: JS-код там либо не нужен вообще, либо нужно 1-2 строки просто для ручного переключения слайдов, все остальное делается через CSS (в том числе и автоматическое переключение слайдов). CSS работает гораздо лучше JS (всегда). Что касается самой GSAP, мало того, что он здесь не нужен, она в принципе нигде не применима. То есть, если подходить к вопросу выбора зависимостей таким образом, что любая зависимость необходима в том, случае, если без нее реализовать сложно или невозможно, тогда GSAP бесполезна во всех вариантах. Главная цель создания GSAP - нарубить бабла. Вся польза притянута за уши.

Comment: @DiD а можно пример автоматического переключения слайдов в ответ к топику с кодом? Там стилей реально 3-5 докинуть  надо или с любым 1м эффектом, чтоб собаки просто поменялись одна за другой и делали это бесконечно. Чисто любопытно.

Comment: Сделал демку на скорую руку, много по-вырезал конечно... JS не использовал.

Comment: Даже оформил на codepen если удобнее https://codepen.io/zazaulola/pen/rNGqYLJ

Comment: @DiD
Спасибо!
Очень интересное решение, но мне ближе на JS - понятнее с управлением и масштабированием. Смысл же не собачек двигать, а сделать обслуживаемое решение. И у Вас чуть информация подгулявшая - GSAP бесплатная либа. 
То - есть после рабочей версии, добавится итератор - длинна массива со слайдами и сколько бы не было слайдов в контейнере - работать и управляться оно будет одинаково. Конечная задача такова. Плюс - рассчёты по фреймам для каждого эффекта. В GSAP и Velocity это делается одним свойством со значением. А так - да, решение супер, если не управлять.

Comment: с gsap строки `let itemsArr = document.querySelectorAll('.bw-photo__image'); itemsArr=Array.from(itemsArr);` можно заменить просто на `let itemsArr = gsap.utils.toArray(".bw-photo__image");`

Comment: Ну что предложили, то и двигаем, можно заменить собак на альпака. Какое решение? Обслуживаемое? Ради какого обслуживания вы добавляете к странице 1.2Мб бесполезных скриптов. С ними код понятнее? А кто обслуживать будет? И какая разница в количестве слайдов? Можно сделать любое динамическое решение и без gsap оно будет короче, нагляднее и самое главное эффективнее.

Comment: @Greg-- спасибо огромное! Тут (без иронии) битва глубоких специалистов CSS с не глубокими JS)))) 
Действительно - утилитарный метод GSAP решает ещё 2 строки.

Comment: @DiD Ну, начнём с того, что надо им управлять и  всё то же самое на ванила JS надо будет написать, кроме 3х строк - присвоение tl, строка с эффектом появления и строка с эффектом угасания, то есть 3 строки кода против всего, что в keyframes, ну как бы, где короче, нагляднее и эффективнее..? Я наперёд забегу, если он не управляемый - там другая логика в GSAP и всего будет 6-7 строк. Далее - это может жить как модуль и отдельно от CSS - для работы в проекте - кинул библиотеку, мод импортнул и работай с любой разметкой. Я написал - да интересно, но чуть сложнее. И 1,2 мб... как бы IBM486  dead))

Comment: Да я уже понял, что вы из таких сайтоделов, которые подключают по много-мегабайтной библиотеки на каждую рюшку на странице. Вот поэтому у вас и тормозит всё. Оптимизация работы вкладок браузера там не причем. Я надеюсь, мне никогда не посчастливится попасть на сделаный вами сайт. Хотя именно из-за этого во всех браузерах стоит расширение uMatrix, блокирующее выполнения всех скриптов до попадания их в белый список. Так что, в принципе, делайте как считаете нужным. С GSAP у вас 1.2Мб скриптов, а без GSAP вы накодите скриптов больше чем на 1.2Мб? Мне искренне жаль. Вам нужно набираться опыта.

Comment: @DiD эээм... Ну первое - решение GSAP и Velocity неоднократно упоминаются как малоресурсные и высокопроизводительные в том же MDN. И именно по этому они берутся в стек для больших проектов или в условиях работы в жёстком дедлайне. Плюс - я ж не просто так написал про блокировку, в отличие от стандартных интервалов (и рекурсивных таймаутов) JS - утилитарные методы GSAP не блокируются браузером - лично проверенно и на этом примере тоже. А Про сайты - я выше написал в чём смысл, но вижу, что не встретил понимания, За оценку спасибо - работаем!

Comment: Вы когда открываете браузер или новую вкладку, если у вас стартовая страница от браузера по-умолчанию, откройте исходный код этой страницы, откройте исходный код ошибки соединения хрома с dino. Что-то я не видел там ни gsap ни даже jquery.

Comment: @DiD сори, но это - мой последний ответ. Вы не читаете, что я Вам пишу, а просто несёте своё - нет смысла в таких дискуссиях. Ещё раз, последний - я проверил лично, на 3х браузерах  - код на ваниле работает, но 10 - 15 мин неактивной вкладки и возврат туда - сбивает таймауты. Метод delayedCall от GSAP решает эту проблему полностью и не зависит от времени отсутствия активности на вкладке. Можете проверить сами - замените соответствующие методы в моей функции, конкретно моя - под рекурсивный setTimeout написана и что угодно можно смотреть на стартовых, есть результат и он работает как заявлено.

Comment: @Артёмка какой delayedCall? Вы вообще о чем? Просто останавливайте все свои setTimeout и setInterval при переключении вкладок. После переключения на вкладку снова включаете анимацию. Это же так просто и для этого не обязательно нужен GSAP!

Comment: Цитата из MDN `По факту, в большинстве случаев, производительность анимаций CSS практически идентична анимациям на JavaScript. По крайней мере в Firefox. Авторы некоторых JavaScript библиотек для анимации, например GSAP или Velocity.JS, даже берутся утверждать, что их решения могут работать быстрее, чем аналогичные решения на CSS. Такое возможно, потому что [...]. Если обе анимации выполняются в одном потоке, то разницы в производительности не будет.

В следующей секции мы пройдёмся по тестам производительности, используя Firefox, чтобы увидеть, какие методы анимации работают эффективнее.`

Comment: Собственно, [ссылка на  MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance). Потому не надо наговаривать на MDN, их упоминание  **GSAP или Velocity.JS** исключительно в негативном ключе (если вы способны уловить контекст).

Comment: Когда gsap из 62кб превратился в 1,2Мб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался - надо проверять оба условия, которые в ифе))))
Сори за беспокойство - сам нашёл))))

```
function slideOn(){
    if(active && index<3){
        gsaping(index);
        gsap.delayedCall(4,()=>{
            slideOn(index); 
        });
    }else if(active) { //тут ошибка в функции <else> нужно с условием, чтоб active проверялось
        index=0;
        slider.innerHTML=reset;
            slideOn(index);//пауза не нужна - лишнее замедление
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как и говорил, JS там не нужен вообще. А тем более платный GSAP.

Прошу прощения что на скорую руку. Совсем нет времени подбирать размеры этих рамок. Чуть позже сделаю описание. Может, оформлю чуть ближе к вашему коду.

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box;}

body{ margin: 0; min-height: 100vh;}

.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.b-wrapper_photo{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 300vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  animation: slide_rotator 15s linear infinite;
}

.bw-photo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bw-photo__image{
    display:block;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
    animation: slide_show 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide_rotator{
  0% { transform: translateY(0vh); }
  33% { transform: translateY(0vh); }
  33.1% { transform: translateY(-100vh); }
  66% { transform: translateY(-100vh); }
  66.1% { transform: translateY(-200vh); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-200vh); }
}

@keyframes slide_show{
  0% { opacity:0; transform: translate(-50px, -50px); filter: blur(5px); }
  40% { opacity:1; transform: translate(0px, 0px); filter: blur(0px); }
  60% { opacity:1; transform: translate(0px, 0px); filter: blur(0px); }
  100% { opacity:0; transform: translate(50px, 50px); filter: blur(25px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="b-wrapper_photo">
       <div class="bw-photo"><img data-count="0" class="bw-photo__image bw-photo__image-inactive" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WVcGJyUWBgFRRWxuAkDKQYpJlo-7O7s4" alt=""></div>
    <div class="bw-photo"><img data-count="1" class="bw-photo__image bw-photo__image-inactive" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-DMaKrgEsMaew0SigzPbrGw4HzsH9J7B" alt=""></div>
    <div class="bw-photo"><img data-count="2" class="bw-photo__image bw-photo__image-inactive" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=151ZB_6AAZiLJqpduAqAjAxVk2v9_-K0k" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте для чистоты эксперимента - кидайте по-своему управление вправо и влево, счётчик слайдов, смотрим стабильность работы и ставим тут второй ответ. Можем вынести в отдельную тему По слайдерам оба решения. Просто тут - вопрос был по хендлеру, как бы и я надеюсь необходимость листенера и рабочего хендлера для функционирования слайдера вы отрицать не будете, равно как и пытаться их заменить CSS))))